# Relationships(joining) of Entities from different EntityManagerFactory, PersistentUnit

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am developing a multi-tenant web application.

Technologies stack used is 
Spring web MVC 3.2.x,
Spring Data JPA 1.4.3,
EclipseLink 2.5.1.

I need to keep all common data such as a countries, locales etc into a separate-single  database schema and all tenant's data such as USERS,HISTORY everything into a single shared database schema (Discriminator based model).

So,Entity model will be something like,

**Common Master Data Entity -Country**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "country")
public class Country implements Serializable{

@GeneratedValue(generator = "assigned-by-code")
@GenericGenerator(name = "assigned-by-code", strategy = "assigned")
private String isoCode;

private String name;
}
```

**Tenant Entity**

```
@Entity
@Multitenant
@Table (name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@Column (name = "username")
private String userName;

@Column (name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column (name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column (name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
...
}
```

So, I achieved above mentioned isolation by having two different **entityManagerFactory** for MASTER and TENANT as below

**FOR TENANT**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="raoutingDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="tenant" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">${hibernate.archive.autodetection}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.sample.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**FOR MASTER**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory_master"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="driverManagerDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="master" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">${hibernate.archive.autodetection}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.sample.master</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now what I want to do is,
I want to associate country.isocode as a joinedcolummn to **User.java** and hence I changed my **User.Java** as below

```
@Entity
@Multitenant
@Table (name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@Column (name = "username")
private String userName;

@Column (name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column (name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column (name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Country.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "countryisocode", referencedColumnName = "isocode")
private Country country;

...
}
```

But on server start up, it is giving error like,

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [tenant] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class com.sample.entity.User] uses a non-entity [class com.sample.master.Country] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field country].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954) [eclipselink-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
```

Please do needful as I do not want to duplicate MASTER tables into each tenant's datasource and hence I need it at a separate place.

Answer (score 1):

As the Country Entity doesn't exist in the tenant factory, it cannot understand the reference.   You need to combine the persistence units into one for the references to work.

If you must keep them separate, EclipseLink supports what it calls a composite persistencde unit, allowing relationships between composite members.  This is described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Composite_Persistence_Units 
and seems to be what you want.  This allows you to use a composite persistence unit for your tenants while reads/writes should go through to the different persistence unit definitions underneath.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I came to know that EclipseLink can help me in this case. But it needs persistence.xml file to be present.Is there any way that I can configure EclipseLink Composite PesistentUnit and its composite members in the same way of Spring configuration described above?

Comment: Any One plz respond on this. @Stackoverflow, please do needful